# Bootstrap 4 - How to make card take 100% width of container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to do something similar to this :

[image]

The content you see is meant to be in a card, but I can't find the right combination to have a similar html structure in bootstrap so far.

The card has to take all the container width, and inside I need to display a video on the left side, a text in the middle and a button on the right side.

Any tips on that ?

I did this so far :

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            VIDEO
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            TEXT
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            BTN
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you have try? post your code.

Comment: Whats the actual problem is responsive in mobile view or small devices ?

Comment: Just realised that I wrongly added a max-width to the original card class, that's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this is good bootstrap ptactice as I am fairly new to bootstrap. But seeing as you want defined widths for each section of the cards, I would suggest using bootstrap columns. And to make the card the full width, set the width to 100%.

How about something like this https://www.codeply.com/p/ab6ZHcUHBs
Code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <video wisth="200" height="150" controls>
                    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTiz2oNaw0c">
                </video>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis quo modi voluptas minima voluptates suscipit doloribus, maiores voluptatem eum placeat?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-3">
                <button>Some button</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to make the same as you want in bootstrap 4. For image width and height you have to write media query for different viewport. Please have a look at it and let me know. if it is same as you want or i have to edit or do something else you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                <video width="200" height="150" controls>
                    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTiz2oNaw0c">
                </video>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-3 col-md-3">
                <button>Button</button>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card mt-3">
    <div class="row p-3">
      <div class="col-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
        <img src="" width="250" height="150" class="border border-2 border-dark">
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-4">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```